# remove specified elements from an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

a doc:

```
{"_id":1,"m":[{"id":1,"m":11},{"id":2,"m":22},{"id":3,"m":33}]}
```

I want remove "m.id" == 1 AND "m.id" == 2 in single update. I can use $in, like:

```
update({"_id":1},{$pull:{"m":{$in:[{"id":1,"m":11},{"id":2,"m":22}]}}})
```

But it requires the whole doc rather than "m.id" $in [1,2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only specify the `id` property from the `m array objects`, you can run the following query:

```
db.test.update({_id: 1}, {
    $pull: {
        m: {
            id: {
                $in: [1,2]
            }
        }
    }
});
```